# React rerender form options based on selected value

Tags: reactjs

Here is my form component:

```
class TransactionList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            product_list: [],

        }
    }



    loadProduct(company){
        let url = window.location.href + "?product=True&company=" + company;
        $.ajax(url, {
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data['data']);
                this.setState({product_list: data['data']});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    }


    handleCompanyChange(event) {
        this.setState({company: event.target.value});
        this.loadProduct(event.target.value);
    }

    handleProductChange(event) {
        this.setState({product: event.target.value});
    }


    render() {

        const {company, product,} = this.state;
        return (
            <form method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label><strong>Company</strong></label>
                    <select className="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" value={company} onChange={this.handleCompanyChange.bind(this)} required>
                        // options list
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label><strong>Product</strong></label>
                    <select value={product} onChange={this.handleProductChange.bind(this)} className="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
                        <option defaultValue={'selected'}>Select Product</option>
                        {this.state.product_list.map(function(name, i){
                            return (<option value={name.name} key={i}>{name.name}</option>);
                        })}
                    </select>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </form>

        )
    }

}


ReactDOM.render(<TransactionList />, document.getElementById("transaction_js_list"));
```

Now I want to get product list based on company field's value.I am sure it can set `product_list` state successfully. But after state change how can I re-render options list in Product input ?

Comment: can you explain better so we can help you more.if you select company then the selected value set to the state why the products list should be re render. Are you facing any problem with that if yes explain the problem clearly

Comment: Your code is quite clear and it should work. So can you please share where are you facing the issue?

Comment: Product list is not re rendering when  company selected value changed.

Comment: Why are you using `<form method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>` ? I don't see `handleSubmit` in your code. May be you should remove `<Form>` tag from your code?

Comment: @Fyodor because I think its not relevant for this problem, thats why I didn't include handleSubmit

Comment: Hope you find your solution here!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50195768/react-js-how-do-i-bind-json-data-to-a-dropdown-list